# How to handle Empty string and NULL the same way in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need the data from four columns (A,B,C,D) in a table. If the columns are non-empty or not null, the I will select the data as result. So, the result should be in the format

```
A:11,C:03
```

or

```
A:12,B:87,C:24,D:01
```

or just

```
' '
```

based on the values the columns hold. My query is treating empty as NOT NULL value and returning me different result than what is expected.

I am expecting D:Remote for both rows. Whereas I am getting A:,B:,C:,D:Remote

[image]

HEre is the fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cb708aebe2220915f6781864910a3f5b

Comment: You can do ISNULL(A, '') = ''    if you need to trim spaces  ISNULL(TRIM(A), '') = ''

Comment: Or if you want to concat them even if they are NULL you can just do ISNULL(A, '') + ',' + ISNULL(B, '')  and so on.  Depends on what you need but your fiddle has a lot of unnecessary stuff it looks like.  Depends on why you need it this way too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

…

```
select concat_ws(',', 'a:'+nullif(a,''), 'b:'+nullif(b,''), 'c:'+nullif(c,''), 'd:'+nullif(d,'') )
from t;


select isnull(stuff(concat(',a:'+nullif(a,''), ',b:'+nullif(b,''), ',c:'+nullif(c,''), ',d:'+nullif(d,'')), 1, 1, ''), '')
from t;
```

Comment: @Iptr concat_ws is not supported on SQL Server 2016. Do we have an equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you want you need to add another case looking like this
`when A is null and B is null and C is null and D is not null then 'D:' + D`. The issue you're having is that your case doesn't return anything which results in a NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (A varchar(50) , B varchar(50) , C varchar(50) , D varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
( '' , '' , '', 'Remote'),
( '' , 'Local' , '', 'Remote'),
( null , null , null, 'Remote');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT A, B, C, D
    , REPLACE(x.query('for $x in /root/*[string-length(text()[1]) gt 0]
            return concat(local-name($x), ":", $x)')
            .value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'), SPACE(1), ',') AS Result
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT A, B, C, D
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t(x)
```

**Output**

```
+------------------+
|      Result      |
+------------------+
| D:Remote         |
| B:Local,D:Remote |
| D:Remote         |
+------------------+
```